# Weird behaviour of bwareafilt in MATLAB and what algorithm does it use?

Tags: image, algorithm, matlab, image-processing

I have the following questions:

1. What is the algorithm that `bwareafilt` uses?
2. Weird behaviour: When the input matrix is totally black, I get following error

   ```
   Error using bwpropfilt (line 73)
   Internal error: p must be positive.
   Error in bwareafilt (line 33)
   bw2 = bwpropfilt(bw, 'area', p, direction, conn);
   Error in colour_reception (line 95)
   Iz=bwareafilt(b,1);
   ```

   Actually, I am using this function to take snapshots from a webcam, but when I block my webcam totally, then I get above following error.

---

So I believe it is an error due to some internal implementation mistake.  Is this the case?  How do I overcome this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's answer your questions one at a time:

## What algorithm does `bwareafilt` use?

[`bwareafilt`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/bwareafilt.html) is a function from the image processing toolbox that accepts a binary image and determines unique objects in this image.  To find unique objects, a connected components analysis is performed where each object is assigned a unique ID.  You can think of this as performing a flood fill on each object individually.  A flood fill can be performed using a variety of algorithms - among them is [depth-first search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search) where you can consider an image as a [graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_(abstract_data_type)) where [edges](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GraphEdge.html) are connected to each pixel.  Flood fill in this case visits all of the pixels that are connected to each other until you don't have any more pixels to visit and that are localized within this object.  You then proceed to the next object and repeat the same algorithm until you run out of objects.

After, it determines the "area" for each object by counting how many pixels belong to that object.  Once we determine the area for each object, we can either output an image that retains the top `n` objects or filter the image so that only those objects that are within a certain range of areas get retained.

Given your code above, you are trying to output an image that is the largest object in the binary image.  Therefore, you are using the former, not the latter where `n=1`.

## Weird behaviour with `bwareafilt`

Given the above description of `bwareafilt` and your intended application:

> Actually, I am using this function to take snapshots from a webcam, but when I block my webcam totally, then I get above following error.

... the error is self-explanatory.  When you cover the webcam, the entire frame is black and there are **no objects that are found in the image**.  Because there are no objects in the image, returning the object with the largest area makes no sense because there are no objects to return to begin with.  That's why you are getting the error because you are trying to make `bwareafilt` return an image with the largest object but there aren't any objects in your image to begin with.

As such, if you want to use `bwareafilt`, what I suggest is you check to see if the entire image is black first.  If it **isn't** black, then go ahead and use `bwareafilt`.  If it is, then skip it.

Do something like this, assuming that `b` is the image you're trying to process:

```
if any(b(:))
    Iz = bwareafilt(b, 1);
else
    Iz = b;
end
```

The above code uses [`any`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/any.html) to check to see if there are any white pixels in your image `b` that are **non-zero**.  If there are, then `bwareafilt` should be appropriately called.  If there aren't any white pixels in the image, then simply set the output to be what `b` originally was (which is a dark image anyway).

Answer (score 0):

You can add Conditions to make your function robust to any inputs , for exemple by ading a simple condition to first treat the input image if it is all black or not, based on the condition yo use your function to filter objects.

Comment: I don't think this answers the question.